# CopyFile - save without overwriting existing file

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo, file-copying

What am I doing:

- User clicks a button, a `FileUpload` component (dialog) fires up and he can
  browse for and load a file from his PC.
- When he clicks ok the file gets saved to the disk, in a specific
  location.
- Prior to saving I'm renaming (or rather, saving with a specific name) his file using some string that contain
  data I previously pulled from some DB fields.

Hence, regardless of the name the file has when the user loads it, it gets saved to the disk with his `Firstname` and `LastName`, which I get from some string variables.

`UniMainModule.foldername` = contains the path to the folder where the file gets saved.

`UniMainModule.FirstName` = contains the user's FirstName

`UniMainModule.LastName` = contains the user's LastName

Thus, the file gets saved as `FirstName_LastName.pdf` on the disk at location provided by `foldername` string.

This is the code I'm using:

```
procedure TsomeForm.UniFileUpload1Completed(Sender: TObject; AStream: TFileStream);
var
  DestName : string;
  DestFolder : string;
begin
   DestFolder:=UniServerModule.StartPath+'files\'+UniMainModule.foldername+'\';
   DestName:=DestFolder+UniMainModule.FirstName+'_'+UniMainModule.LastName+'.pdf';
   CopyFile(PChar(AStream.FileName), PChar(DestName), False);
   ModalResult:= mrOk;
end;
```

As I understand it, after reading a bit about `CopyFile` on `msdn` passing `False` means that it should and will overwrite the existing file.

If the file isn't already present with that name in that location, it's fine, it gets saved.

But if the user decides to use the fileupload again and upload a new file, the new file will overwrite the previous one. Since they're being saved with the same name.

How then can you ensure that if the file already exists (a file with that exact name is present in the location) it doesn't get overwritten but, I don't know, gets assigned a (1) in the name or something, keeping both files?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Call `CopyFile()` in a loop, setting its `bFailIfExists` parameter to `TRUE` so you can retry with a new filename if `CopyFile()` fails with an `ERROR_FILE_EXISTS` error code.

For example:

```
procedure TsomeForm.UniFileUpload1Completed(Sender: TObject; AStream: TFileStream);
var
  DestName : string;
  DestFolder : string;
  n : integer;
begin
  DestFolder := UniServerModule.StartPath + 'files\' + UniMainModule.foldername + '\';
  DestName := UniMainModule.FirstName + '_' + UniMainModule.LastName + '.pdf';
  n := 0;

  while not CopyFile(PChar(AStream.FileName), PChar(DestFolder + DestName), True) do
  begin
    if GetLastError() <> ERROR_FILE_EXISTS then
    begin
      // error handling...
      Break;
    end;
    Inc(n);
    DestName := UniMainModule.FirstName + '_' + UniMainModule.LastName + ' (' + IntToStr(n) + ').pdf';
  end;

  ModalResult := mrOk;
end;
```

However, rather than handling this manually, you should let the OS do the work for you. Especially since the OS has its own way to renaming copied files, and that naming scheme can change (and has) from one OS version to another.

Instead of using `CopyFile()`, use [`SHFileOperation()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164.aspx) instead, which has a `FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION` flag:

> Give the file being operated on a new name in a move, copy, or rename operation if a file with the target name already exists at the destination.

For example:

```
uses
  ..., Winapi.ShellAPI;

procedure TsomeForm.UniFileUpload1Completed(Sender: TObject; AStream: TFileStream);
var
  DestName : string;
  DestFolder : string;
  fo : TSHFileOpStruct;
begin
  DestFolder := UniServerModule.StartPath + 'files\' + UniMainModule.foldername + '\';
  DestName := DestFolder + UniMainModule.FirstName + '_' + UniMainModule.LastName + '.pdf';

  ZeroMemory(@fo, SizeOf(fo));
  fo.Wnd := Handle;
  fo.wFunc := FO_COPY;
  fo.pFrom := PChar(AStream.FileName+#0);
  fo.pTo := PChar(DestName+#0);
  fo.fFlags := FOF_SILENT or FOF_NOCONFIRMATION or FOF_NOERRORUI or FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR or FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION;

  if SHFileOperation(fo) <> 0 then
  begin
    // error handling...
  end
  else if fo.fAnyOperationsAborted then
  begin
    // abort handling ...
  end;

  ModalResult := mrOk;
end;
```

If you need to know what the OS picked for the renamed filename, there is also a `FOF_WANTMAPPINGHANDLE` flag:

> If FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION is specified and any files were renamed, assign a name mapping object that contains their old and new names to the `hNameMappings` member. This object must be freed using [`SHFreeNameMappings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762171.aspx) when it is no longer needed.

For example:

```
uses
  ..., Winapi.ShellAPI;

type
  PHandleToMappings = ^THandleToMappings;
  THandleToMappings = record
    uNumberOfMappings: UINT;                          // Number of mappings in the array.
    lpSHNameMappings: array[0..0] of PSHNAMEMAPPINGW; // array of pointers to mappings.
  end;

procedure TsomeForm.UniFileUpload1Completed(Sender: TObject; AStream: TFileStream);
var
  DestName : string;
  DestFolder : string;
  fo : TSHFileOpStruct;
  pMappings : PHandleToMappings;
  pMapping : PSHNAMEMAPPINGW;
begin
  DestFolder := UniServerModule.StartPath + 'files\' + UniMainModule.foldername + '\';
  DestName := DestFolder + UniMainModule.FirstName + '_' + UniMainModule.LastName + '.pdf';

  ZeroMemory(@fo, SizeOf(fo));
  fo.Wnd := Handle;
  fo.wFunc := FO_COPY;
  fo.pFrom := PChar(AStream.FileName+#0);
  fo.pTo := PChar(DestName+#0);
  fo.fFlags := FOF_SILENT or FOF_NOCONFIRMATION or FOF_NOERRORUI or FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR or FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION or FOF_WANTMAPPINGHANDLE;

  if SHFileOperation(fo) <> 0 then
  begin
    // error handling...
  end else
  begin
    if fo.fAnyOperationsAborted then
    begin
      // abort handling...
    end;

    if fo.hNameMappings <> nil then
    begin
      try
        pMappings := PHandleToMappings(fo.hNameMappings);
        pMapping := pMappings^.lpSHNameMappings[0];
        SetString(DestName, pMapping^.pszNewPath, pMapping^.cchNewPath);
      finally
        SHFreeNameMappings(THandle(fo.hNameMappings));
      end;
      // use DestName as needed...
    end;
  end;

  ModalResult := mrOk;
end;
```

On Vista and later, you can alternatively use [`IFileOperation.CopyItem()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775761.aspx) instead, which also supports renaming an item on collision. An [`IFileOperationProgressSink`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775722.aspx) callback can be used to discover the new filename if a rename collision occurs.

For example:

```
uses
  ..., Winapi.ActiveX, Winapi.ShlObj, System.Win.Comobj;

type
  TMyCopyProgressSink = class(TInterfacedObject, IFileOperationProgressSink)
  public
    CopiedName: string;
    function StartOperations: HResult; stdcall;
    function FinishOperations(hrResult: HResult): HResult; stdcall;
    function PreRenameItem(dwFlags: DWORD; const psiItem: IShellItem;
      pszNewName: LPCWSTR): HResult; stdcall;
    function PostRenameItem(dwFlags: DWORD; const psiItem: IShellItem;
      pszNewName: LPCWSTR; hrRename: HResult; const psiNewlyCreated: IShellItem): HResult; stdcall;
    function PreMoveItem(dwFlags: DWORD; const psiItem: IShellItem;
      const psiDestinationFolder: IShellItem; pszNewName: LPCWSTR): HResult; stdcall;
    function PostMoveItem(dwFlags: DWORD; const psiItem: IShellItem;
      const psiDestinationFolder: IShellItem; pszNewName: LPCWSTR;
      hrMove: HResult; const psiNewlyCreated: IShellItem): HResult; stdcall;
    function PreCopyItem(dwFlags: DWORD; const psiItem: IShellItem;
      const psiDestinationFolder: IShellItem; pszNewName: LPCWSTR): HResult; stdcall;
    function PostCopyItem(dwFlags: DWORD; const psiItem: IShellItem;
      const psiDestinationFolder: IShellItem; pszNewName: LPCWSTR;
      hrCopy: HResult; const psiNewlyCreated: IShellItem): HResult; stdcall;
    function PreDeleteItem(dwFlags: DWORD; const psiItem: IShellItem): HResult; stdcall;
    function PostDeleteItem(dwFlags: DWORD; const psiItem: IShellItem; hrDelete: HResult;
      const psiNewlyCreated: IShellItem): HResult; stdcall;
    function PreNewItem(dwFlags: DWORD; const psiDestinationFolder: IShellItem;
      pszNewName: LPCWSTR): HResult; stdcall;
    function PostNewItem(dwFlags: DWORD; const psiDestinationFolder: IShellItem;
      pszNewName: LPCWSTR; pszTemplateName: LPCWSTR; dwFileAttributes: DWORD;
      hrNew: HResult; const psiNewItem: IShellItem): HResult; stdcall;
    function UpdateProgress(iWorkTotal: UINT; iWorkSoFar: UINT): HResult; stdcall;
    function ResetTimer: HResult; stdcall;
    function PauseTimer: HResult; stdcall;
    function ResumeTimer: HResult; stdcall;
  end;

function TMyCopyProgressSink.StartOperations: HResult; stdcall;
begin
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TMyCopyProgressSink.FinishOperations(hrResult: HResult): HResult; stdcall;
begin
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TMyCopyProgressSink.PreRenameItem(dwFlags: DWORD; const psiItem: IShellItem;
  pszNewName: LPCWSTR): HResult; stdcall;
begin
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TMyCopyProgressSink.PostRenameItem(dwFlags: DWORD; const psiItem: IShellItem;
  pszNewName: LPCWSTR; hrRename: HResult; const psiNewlyCreated: IShellItem): HResult; stdcall;
begin
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TMyCopyProgressSink.PreMoveItem(dwFlags: DWORD; const psiItem: IShellItem;
  const psiDestinationFolder: IShellItem; pszNewName: LPCWSTR): HResult; stdcall;
begin
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TMyCopyProgressSink.PostMoveItem(dwFlags: DWORD; const psiItem: IShellItem;
  const psiDestinationFolder: IShellItem; pszNewName: LPCWSTR;
  hrMove: HResult; const psiNewlyCreated: IShellItem): HResult; stdcall;
begin
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TMyCopyProgressSink.PreCopyItem(dwFlags: DWORD; const psiItem: IShellItem;
  const psiDestinationFolder: IShellItem; pszNewName: LPCWSTR): HResult; stdcall;
begin
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TMyCopyProgressSink.PostCopyItem(dwFlags: DWORD; const psiItem: IShellItem;
  const psiDestinationFolder: IShellItem; pszNewName: LPCWSTR;
  hrCopy: HResult; const psiNewlyCreated: IShellItem): HResult; stdcall;
begin
  CopiedName := pszNewName;
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TMyCopyProgressSink.PreDeleteItem(dwFlags: DWORD; const psiItem: IShellItem): HResult; stdcall;
begin
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TMyCopyProgressSink.PostDeleteItem(dwFlags: DWORD; const psiItem: IShellItem; hrDelete: HResult;
  const psiNewlyCreated: IShellItem): HResult; stdcall;
begin
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TMyCopyProgressSink.PreNewItem(dwFlags: DWORD; const psiDestinationFolder: IShellItem;
  pszNewName: LPCWSTR): HResult; stdcall;
begin
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TMyCopyProgressSink.PostNewItem(dwFlags: DWORD; const psiDestinationFolder: IShellItem;
  pszNewName: LPCWSTR; pszTemplateName: LPCWSTR; dwFileAttributes: DWORD;
  hrNew: HResult; const psiNewItem: IShellItem): HResult; stdcall;
begin
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TMyCopyProgressSink.UpdateProgress(iWorkTotal: UINT; iWorkSoFar: UINT): HResult; stdcall;
begin
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TMyCopyProgressSink.ResetTimer: HResult; stdcall;
begin
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TMyCopyProgressSink.PauseTimer: HResult; stdcall;
begin
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TMyCopyProgressSink.ResumeTimer: HResult; stdcall;
begin
  Result := S_OK;
end;

procedure TsomeForm.UniFileUpload1Completed(Sender: TObject; AStream: TFileStream);
var
  DestName : string;
  DestFolder : string;
  pfo : IFileOperation;
  psiFrom : IShellItem;
  psiTo : IShellItem;
  Sink : IFileOperationProgressSink;
  bAborted : BOOL;
begin
  DestFolder := UniServerModule.StartPath + 'files\' + UniMainModule.foldername + '\';
  DestName := UniMainModule.FirstName + '_' + UniMainModule.LastName + '.pdf';

  try
    OleCheck(SHCreateItemFromParsingName(PChar(AStream.FileName), nil, IShellItem, psiFrom));
    OleCheck(SHCreateItemFromParsingName(PChar(DestFolder), nil, IShellItem, psiTo));

    OleCheck(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOperation, nil, CLSCTX_ALL, IFileOperation, pfo));
    OleCheck(pfo.SetOperationFlags(FOF_SILENT or FOF_NOCONFIRMATION or FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR or FOF_NOERRORUI or FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION or FOFX_PRESERVEFILEEXTENSIONS));

    Sink := TMyCopyProgressSink.Create;
    OleCheck(pfo.CopyItem(psiFrom, psiTo, PChar(DestName), Sink));
    OleCheck(pfo.PerformOperations());

    pfo.GetAnyOperationsAborted(bAborted);
    if bAborted then
    begin
      // abort handling...
    end;

    DestName := TMyCopyProgressSink(Sink).CopiedName;
    // use DestName as needed...
  except
    // error handling...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @Remy Lebeau - Thank you for an incredibly well-written and detailed answer, I'll definitely give it a go!

Answer (score 5):

You have a file name, so use FileExists to check if file exists. If it does append a (1) to the file name and try again. repeat for increasing n until you get a file name that does not exist. so, a bit like this:

```
procedure TsomeForm.UniFileUpload1Completed(Sender: TObject; AStream: TFileStream);
var
  DestName : string;
  DestFolder : string;
  n : integer;
  additional : string;
begin
   DestFolder:=UniServerModule.StartPath+'files\'+UniMainModule.foldername+'\';
   DestName:=DestFolder+UniMainModule.FirstName+'_'+UniMainModule.LastName;
   n := 0;
   additional :='.pdf';
   while FileExists( DestName + additional ) do
   begin
     inc(n);
     additional := '(' + intToStr(n) + ')'+'.pdf';
   end;
   CopyFile(PChar(AStream.FileName), PChar(DestName + additional), False);
   ModalResult:= mrOk;
end;
```

Comment: Using `FileExists()` in this manner is a race condition. It would be safer to call `CopyFile()` in a loop with `bFailIfExists=TRUE` instead, retrying with a new filename if `CopyFile()` fails with `ERROR_FILE_EXISTS`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my take on a solution

```
    procedure TsomeForm.UniFileUpload1Completed(Sender: TObject; AStream: TFileStream);
    var
      DestName, NewName : string;
      DestFolder : string;
      Cnt: integer;
    begin
      DestFolder:=UniServerModule.StartPath+'files\'+UniMainModule.foldername+'\';
      DestName:=DestFolder+UniMainModule.FirstName+'_'+UniMainModule.LastName+'.pdf';
      if FileExists(DestName) then begin
        Cnt:=0;
        repeat
          Inc(Cnt);
          NewName:=Format(DestFolder+UniMainModule.FirstName+'_'+UniMainModule.LastName+'(%d).pdf',[Cnt]);
        until not FileExists(NewName);
        DestName:=NewName;
      end;
      CopyFile(PChar(AStream.FileName), PChar(DestName), False);
      ModalResult:= mrOk;
    end;
```

Comment: Using `FileExists()` in this manner is a race condition. It would be safer to call `CopyFile()` in a loop with `bFailIfExists=TRUE` instead, retrying with a new filename if `CopyFile()` fails with `ERROR_FILE_EXISTS`.